# How can I use UploadField within GridFieldEditableColumns in SilverStripe 4?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a problem with `GridFieldEditableColumns`. I extended `EditableOption` with a list of files, and now I want the CMS columns to display an upload field. I took the `EditableMultipleOptionField` as a reference and implemented it like this:

```
$editableColumns = new GridFieldEditableColumns();
$editableColumns->setDisplayFields([
    'Title' => [
        'title' => 'Beschreibung',
        'callback' => function ($record, $column, $grid) {
            return TextField::create($column);
        }
    ],
    'Value' => [
        'title' => 'Wert',
        'callback' => function ($record, $column, $grid) {
            return TextField::create($column);
        }
    ],
    'Default' => [
        'title' => 'Standardmäßig aktiv?',
        'callback' => function ($record, $column, $grid) {
            return CheckboxField::create($column);
        }
    ],
    'Examples' => [
        'title' => 'Beispielbilder',
        'callback' => function ($record, $column, $grid) {
            return UploadField::create($column);
        }
    ]
]);
```

However, I always get errors when I use `UploadField`:

> [Emergency] Uncaught LogicException: Field must be associated with a form to call Link(). Please use $field->setForm($form);

I also tried it with `['field' => UploadField::class]`, same problem. The extension works, because if I change the field for the `DataObject` to type `Text` and use a `TextField` instead, it works fine. How can I use an `UploadField` within `GridFieldEditableColumns`?